# setInterval not being able to access variables in react

Tags: reactjs

A simple react script:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export default function App() {
    const [indexesArray, setIndexesArray] = useState([]);

    const doit = () => {
        const arr = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<10;i++){
            arr.push(i);
        }
        setIndexesArray(arr);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!indexesArray.length){
            doit();
            setInterval(function(){
                console.log('indexesArray',indexesArray);
            }, 2000);
        }
        
    }, [indexesArray]);

    return (
      <>
        {indexesArray && JSON.stringify(indexesArray)}
      </>
  );
}
```

On the page I can see the content of the array. However, printing the array in the console each 2 seconds shows an empty array. What am I missing?

Comment: setInterval(() => { console.log('indexesArray',indexesArray);}, 2000);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `indexesArray` binding being used by the `setInterval` is the array that exist in the scope *that the interval was created* - which is empty. Re-rendering of the components doesn't *mutate* the existing state - it runs the whole `app` again, in a whole different scope (but this time with new values returned by `useState`).

In your effect hook, set the interval only if the array has been populated (and don't forget to clear the interval afterwards).

```js
function App() {
    const [indexesArray, setIndexesArray] = React.useState([]);

    const doit = () => {
        const arr = [];
        for(let i = 0;i<10;i++){
            arr.push(i);
        }
        setIndexesArray(arr);
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if(!indexesArray.length){
            doit();
        } else {
            const intervalId = setInterval(function(){
                console.log('indexesArray',indexesArray);
            }, 2000);
            return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        
    }, [indexesArray]);

    return indexesArray && JSON.stringify(indexesArray)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```